# Maven is unable to find a package from the local repository

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

I am encountering a weird issue.

I have two spring-boot projects built using maven. They are named `customers` and `rest-client`.
They are based on `spring-boot 3.2.2` and use Maven as the build tool.

Maven version on my machine:

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
```

Java version:

```
java 21 2023-09-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21+35.1 (build 21+35-jvmci-23.1-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21+35.1 (build 21+35-jvmci-23.1-b15, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The `rest-client` project is dependent on the `customers` project as it uses a DTO (Java record).

I have added the dependency in the `rest-client` pom.xml as below

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adityasamant.learnings</groupId>
            <artifactId>customers</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

The jar is present in the local Maven repository as seen below:

```
/Users/adityasamant/.m2/repository/com/adityasamant/learnings/customers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
adityasamant@Adityas-MacBook-Pro 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT % ls
_remote.repositories            customers-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    customers-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom    maven-metadata-local.xml
```

I have pointed to the local maven repository using the below field in my settings.xml
`<localRepository>/Users/adityasamant/.m2/repository</localRepository>`

The dependencies seem to get resolved in IntelliJ IDEA.

But when I build the `rest-client` project using `mvn clean install`, maven is not able to resolve packages from the `customers` module and throws exceptions in compilation.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project rest-client: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/adityasamant/Documents/work/code/spring/rest-client/src/main/java/com/adityasamant/learnings/restclient/controller/RestClientController.java:[3,50] package com.adityasamant.learnings.customers.model does not exist
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following:

1. I have pointed to the local maven repository using the below field in my settings.xml
   `<localRepository>/Users/adityasamant/.m2/repository</localRepository>`
2. I have also tried to rename the _remote.repositories file under `/Users/adityasamant/.m2/repository/com/adityasamant/learnings/customers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

This did not help.

As the dependencies get resolved in IntelliJ IDEA, I was expecting that the Maven build would pass seamlessly as well.

Comment: A spring boot project itself can not being used as dependency, because a spring boot jar is not a usual jar file.. There are in general two options.. Extract the commons code into a separate project and do not make it a spring boot project... only use deps...the second one is to use Repackage existing `With layout=NONE` in the spring boot maven plugin configuration. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals) but that results in a jar which is not exectuable anymore...

Comment: In this situation I would suggest to create a multi module build which comprises of common, rest-client, customers with a root pom... that gives the option to build in one go...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:
in your `pom.xml` add this repository as child of your `repositories` tag:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>in-project</id>
    <name>In Project Repo</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/maven_repo</url>
</repository>
```

In the directory where you have your pom file (that is the project.basedir for maven), create a dir named `maven_repo` and inside it place your directories so that you will form the path

`maven_repo/com/adityasamant/learnings/customers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

(and in the last folder of your path you will place your jar of course)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it did not help.

I cannot figure out why maven does not pick the jar from the local maven repository. It is present but seems like Maven is not referring to it.

Comment: The reason is because the jar I'm adding as a dependency is a spring boot jar. As I understand, spring boot jars cannot be added directly as a dependency in other projects due to their special structure.

Comment: using that is a bad idea because it will not solve the problem in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is present here:-
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).